# How add a link in only one existing li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

This is my problem: I have a ul list that has undertemined number of li, because it depends the number of the files in a folder. It lists those files in a div, and when the mouse hovers one of them, I want it till get the new link only in its div.

My code is this:

```
function showImages(data) {
    var ul = "<ul id='productImages'>";

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var tempButton = i;
        var link = '@Html.ActionLink("Pedir Detalhes","ContactUs", new { tempVerifyButton = 3}, new { @class = "visualize"})';

        var directories = data[i];
        ul += "<li id = 'element" + i.toString() + "'><img src='../Content/images/Products/" + directories.ImageName + "' /><div class = 'description'><div id = 'productsText'>" + directories.DescriptionName + "</div></div></li>";
    }

    ul += "</ul>";

    $("#directoryImages").append(ul);

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var element = "ul#productImages li#element" + i.toString();
        $(element).hover(
        function () {
            var link = '@Html.ActionLink("Pedir Detalhes","ContactUs", new { tempVerifyButton = 3 }, new { @class = "visualize"})';
            $(".description").append("<div class = 'visualize'>" + link + "</div>");
        });
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is when the mouse hovers one of the li element, all .description gets the link, and I want only the current hovered li till get the link, and then when it loses focus the link disappears.

EDITED:

I already use $(this).append($(".description").append("< div class = 'visualize'>" + link + "< /div>"));

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, use the `this` pointer. This has been asked hundreds of times

Comment: suresh's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: I already edit to be more especific. Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Try with **this**(current element)

```
$(this).append("<div class = 'visualize'>" + link + "</div>");
```

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

> this is a special keyword that is used in methods to refer to the object on which a method is being invoked.

Comment: for that you have to remove before append  `$('.visualize').remove();` Then append.